# How to use array column name inside of object from json return in datatable ajax?

Tags: ajax, datatable, datatables

i try to figure how to write column name of data if the data is array inside object

if the json return looks like

```
"data" : {
            "name" : "aaa"
    }
```

i will use this code

```
        ajax : {
            url : url,
            type : 'GET'
        },
        "scrollX" : true,
        destroy : true,
        columns : [ {
            data : 'name'
        }, ]
```

but how about if the json return looks like

```
"data" : {
            "detail" : [
              {
                  "name" : "abc"
              }
            ]
}
```

i try to write this code below but it not works, can someone help me with this issue

```
 ajax : {
                url : url,
                type : 'GET'
            },
            "scrollX" : true,
            destroy : true,
    columns : [ {
                    data.detail : 'name'
                },
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where the `dataSrc` option for your DataTables `ajax` can be used:

```
ajax : {
  url : url,
  type : 'GET',
  dataSrc: 'data.detail'
},
```

This option tells DataTables that the iteration through your JSON should start at the `data.detail` array of objects.

Normally, (as in your first JSON example), you do not need this directive - as the starting point is assumed to be `data`. This is a DataTables extension to the standard set of jQuery `ajax` options. You can read more about it [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc).

The relevant part is:

> *you can use Javascript dotted object notation to get a data source for multiple levels of object / array nesting.*

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify: After making the above change, you can use your original approach again to identify column data:

```
columns : [ 
  { data : 'name' }, 
  { data : 'another_name' },
  { ... }
]
```